Python Dataframe format mask to clean up freeform data before and after a special character like '-'
I'm exporting a table from a Database into a pandas dataframe and trying to implement a format mask to clean up some freeform text held in a column.
I want to create a new column in the Dataframe to extract all the numbers directly before and after the '-' from an existing column. Note  delimited by any whitespace, shown in the last example.
Here are some of the variations of data I have:
'Widget 1234-12345 Blah Blah',
'12345-12345_A',
'123456-123456 and 6789-12345'
'12 1234567-1234567'

the output should look like this:
1234-12345
12345-12345
123456-123456
1234567-1234567


Use Series.str.extract:
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+-\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
               col
0       1234-12345
1      12345-12345
2    123456-123456
3  1234567-1234567

For all matches is possible use Series.str.findall:
df['col'] = df['col'].str.findall(r'(\d+-\d+)').str.join(', ')
print (df)
                         col
0                 1234-12345
1                12345-12345
2  123456-123456, 6789-12345
3            1234567-1234567

